# Why isn't projection of $\mathbf{v}$ onto $\mathbf{u}$ defined so that it's perpendicular to the straight line segment connecting $\mathbf{u, v}$?

Tags: vectors, visualization

Kuldeep Singh. [*Linear Algebra: Step by Step*](http://www.oup.co.uk/companion/singh)
(2013). p 312

Why isn't $\mathbf{proj_u v}$ defined as the red vector below with $\mathbf{v} \perp \mathbf{d}?$ I already know, but can't intuit why, $\mathbf{proj_u v}$ is defined as the green vector below with $\mathbf{p} \perp \mathbf{u}$.

> [image]

Comment: @PeterForeman Apologies, but doesn't your comment merely beg the question? Why do we "project perpendicular onto the surface of projection"?

Comment: if v is orthogonal to u, your second projection seems to have a problem (also, even if defined, this projection is not linear, and linearity is a very useful property)

Answer (score 3):

It's so we can reconstruct the original vector easily from its projections. If we have an orthonormal basis $B=\{b_1,\dots, b_n\}$ of a vector space $V$, and any vector $v\in V$, then we have

$$v=\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{proj}_{b_i}(v).$$

Essentially, $\operatorname{proj}_uv$ is the "$u$-component" of $v$. For instance, a vector $v=(1,2,3)\in\mathbb R^3$ can be split into its $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-components by projecting it onto the corresponding unit vectors $e_x,e_y,e_z$ and then reconstructed as

$$\operatorname{proj}_{e_x}(v)+\operatorname{proj}_{e_y}(v) +\operatorname{proj}_{e_z}(v)=1e_x+2e_y+3e_z=(1,2,3)=v.$$

This is not as easily done with your way of projecting.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, projection of $\vec v$ onto $\vec u$ is vector $\vec w$ parallel to $\vec u$ such that

$$\vec v=\vec w+\vec p$$

therefore, as an intuition, $\vec v$ is the ***longest vector*** in the triple.

Indeed, in your alternative sketch, $\vec v$ represents the projection of the red vector onto $\vec v$ direction.

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonal parts can be added to give us $u + d = v$ for the canonical version and $v + d = u$ for the version you've drawn in the red box. Note that all you've done is switch the roles of $u$ and $v$ and relabeling the variables doesn't add any additional insight into the problem.